# Where is my rails installation located? Where are the rails plugins?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, location, paperclip, uninstallation

I'm trying to delete a plugin I installed for rails (paperclip). But I actually don't have any idea where I can find my local rails installation directory.

So where can I find rails and rails plugins in my local file system?
I have OS X.

Or how can I uninstall paperclip from the command line?

Thx!

Comment: How did you install it in the first place?

Comment: :-)
One click installer for ruby for os x and then sudo gem install rails

Answer (score 3, accepted):

paperclip is a rails plugin, which means it is in

```
[your rails app directory]/vendor/plugins/paperclip
```

so if you delete that folder, paperclip is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Under the directory vendor/plugins  of directory created by the rails command.

Answer (score 0):

if your environment is cygwin:
/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.3/lib