# Delete/Destroy method doesn't work anymore? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm encountering a very strange problem:  my delete actions in rails don't work anymore.

Even if I create everything by the scaffold command, every click on delete just sends me to the show view of the object, which should be deleted.

```
script/generate scaffold myitem description:text
```

This isn't only in one project, but extends to new projects I create.
Any idea, where this is coming from? Or better: Any idea how to fix this?

(the only thing I can think of, is that some plugin broke my installation, I installed paperclip, but don't know how to uninstall it: [where are my plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/635136/where-is-my-rails-installation-located-where-are-the-rails-plugins))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the problem was probably Firefox. When I clicked on *Answer you own question* here on Stackoverflow, I had the very same problem: My request, wasn't processed properly. I was sent back to the normal question view, without having the ability to submit my own answer.

So after a restart of Firefox everything worked fine.

(I also reinstalled Ruby and Rails at the same time, so I can't be sure, if it was Firefox for sure).

Answer (score 1):

Removing link to jquery helped me.

Comment: so how can we get around this problem if i need jquery?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to look in the log file to see what SQL is being generated for the delete, and what error it is being generated.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before (because I had the same problem). Perhaps this could help you:

[Rails 3 :method=> :delete doesn't work in Internet Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772450/rails-3-method-delete-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer)

Answer (score 0):

I follow [this blog](http://www.iamseree.com/application-development/rails-3-destroy-did-not-work-the-solution) step by step and solve it!

Comment: 404 page not found.