# How to use :confirm with button_to and :method :put?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have some destructive action to be performed, so I think it's Rails way to put such actions behind a PUT or POST (so link_to doesn't work because it only GETs).

I added a button like this:

```
<%= button_to "Acknowledge", ack_something_path, :method => :put, :confirm => "Sure?" %>
```

The button works (calls the correct action), but, I can't get Rails to show a "confirm" dialog box.

Any ideas how to do that ?

**UPDATE (PROBLEM SOLVED)**

I didn't mention that I was including jquery as well as prototype in `HEAD` (didn't think it would matter). BUT, *when I removed jquery*, the confirmation dialog was displayed.

Don't know why this happens, but problem is solved (for now anyway). jquery and prototype do not like to work together it seems.

Comment: Actually jQuery and Prototype both define their own `$` method. To solve, call `jQuery.noConflict()` after the jquery lib is included. After that, use `jQuery` for jquery's $ method, and use `$` for prototype's $ method.

Comment: Nice to know, thanks! Also, when I included jQuery before the `javascript_include_tag :defaults`, it worked (i.e. without calling `noConflict()`)! (Note to self: http://www.alfajango.com/blog/rails-prototype-to-jquery/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could show the confirm dialog box when I copy your code to my view.

Did you include correct javascript file in the `<head>` section? The js file at `public/javascripts/rails.js` is needed to enable all the js effect in view helper methods.

You can check whether `<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>` is in the `head` or not.

Comment: I checked... the rails.js is being included in the page, and the file exists as well.