# Rails 3 Confirm Delete - in IE8, pressing Cancel still deletes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, internet-explorer-8

Following Michael Hartl's tutorial. Using Rails 3.0.9 under Ubuntu. The following header is in application.html.erb:

```
<head>
  <title><%= title %></title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
  <%= render 'layouts/stylesheets' %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
</head>
```

No jQuery.  Tutorial [Listing 10.38](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/updating-showing-and-deleting-users#code%3adelete_links) specifies the Delete action be called as follows:

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?",
                            :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

Here is an example of the generated HTML:

```
<a href="/users/13" data-confirm="You sure?" data-method="delete" 
 rel="nofollow" title="Delete Mylene Gaylord">delete</a>
```

I've tested the confirmation under three browsers:

- Firefox 3 under Ubuntu:  "OK" deletes user, "Cancel" does not (good)
- Firefox 5 under Win7:  "OK" deletes user, "Cancel" does not (good)
- IE8 under Win7:  both "OK" and "Cancel" delete user (bad!)

When using IE8, why is Cancel calling the Delete code, and how do I fix it?  Is there a way to test that Cancel does, in fact, cancel the action, no matter what browser is used?

Update 9/29/2011:  after upgrading to Rails 3.1 and converting from Prototype to jQuery (Tutorial section [13.1.4](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-3-1#sec%3aprototype_to_jquery)), IE8 behaves properly:  pressing Cancel aborts the delete action.  However that doesn't answer the original question of why IE8 can't Cancel the delete from Rails 3.0.9 with Prototype.

Comment: It seems that there's a similar question about the same subject in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3772450/rails-3-method-delete-doesnt-work-in-internet-explorer

Comment: Thanks @AndreDurao. I saw that but I think this is different. I'm not using jQuery, I'm using a later version of Rails, and I _do_ get the popups; it's just that in IE8, the Cancel button doesn't cancel the action.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you include this in you head.

`app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
    </head> 
    <body>
        HtML
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, that is is in there. I've edited the question above to show the full `<head>` section for clarity.