# Rails 3.1 link_to not showing confirmation or destroying properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, railstutorial.org, link-to

I've been plowing through the chapters at railstutorial.org and been using Rails 3.1.3 because I'm crazy and/or wanted a challenge. I managed to figure out most version problems easily but this one stumped me for a while.

In 10.4.2, Michael Hartl uses the following code to delete users:

```
<%= link_to "delete", user, :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?", 
                            :title => "Delete #{user.name}" %>
```

It doesn't work properly if you test it in the browser (chrome) and instead sends you to that user page.

It is supposed to work if you include this:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
```

but it fails with Rails 3.1 (it should work for Rails 3.0 though, or so I hear).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So for all of you pulling out your hair for using Rails 3.1, here's the solution.

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

Using "application" instead of :defaults solves this problem, delete and confirm should work, now get back to coding!

Special thanks to [George Shaw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007211/george-shaw) for this answer over on https://stackoverflow.com/a/8350158/1127011 .

And it case you were wondering, title is for mouseover only.

Answer (score 0):

The a HTML tag will always fire the GET method. Rails uses the Javascript driver to replace the HTTP verb. The link_to method will fallback any method (post, put and delete) to get (corresponding to the show action) when :

- Javascript has been disabled by the user
- for some reason, Rails unobtrusive javascript driver is not handling the link properly

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html

I suspect the second reason to be the issue. Make sure the jquery.js, application.js, jquery_ujs.js file are included.

Instead of link_to, you could try to use button_to which creates a form allowing put, post and delete methods without Javascript enabled.

Comment: Curiously, when I used the button_to, it did allow me to delete (yay), but still provided no confirmation window (boo) so it still wasn't working properly.