# link_to delete post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this code:

```
<table>
 <% @posts.each do |post| %>
  <tr>
   <td><%= post.created_at.utc.strftime("%d.%m.%Y") %></td>
   <td><%= link_to(post.title, {:controller=>:blog,:action=>:show, :id=>post}) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(post) %></td>
   <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', {:controller=>:posts,:action=>:destroy, :id=>post}, :method=>:delete %></td>
 </tr>
<% end %>
```

Problem is that link_to 'Destroy' isn't deleting posts, but just open them. Any suggestions to solve this?

routes.rb file:

```
LivuPamatskola::Application.routes.draw do
resources :posts
get "admin/rakstu_red"
get "home/par_skolu"
get "home/personals"
get "home/kontakti"
get "home/pers_pieeja"
get "home/galerijas"
get "home/index"
root :to => 'home#index'
```

posts.controller.rb destroy section:

```
def destroy
   @post = Post.find(params[:id])
   @post.destroy

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html { redirect_to posts_url }
     format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
// WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
// GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

layout head:

```
<head>
<title>Līvu pamatskola</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'style' %>
<%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
</head>
```

**SOLVED:**

Found solution on this post: [Rails 3.1 link_to not showing confirmation or destroying properly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8726534/rails-3-1-link-to-not-showing-confirmation-or-destroying-properly)

Anyway, thank you guys for helping!

Answer (score 3):

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', post, :method => :delete, :confirm => "Are you sure?" %>
```

also you could clean a little edit link

```
<%= link_to post.title, post %>
```

And edit link

```
<%= link_to 'Edit', [:edit, post] %>
```

Comment: 1. show your `routes.rb` file, 2. show your `posts_controller.rb` file

Comment: Hm. Everything looks ok. The reason could be that you have switched off your javascript in browser. Can you show what HTML code your destroy link generates?

Comment: Кликнуть правой кнопкой мыши в браузере и найти что-то вроде "Просмотр кода страницы"

Comment: it is not a html it is link. Can you put it like a raw string

Comment: <td><a href="/posts/26" data-confirm="Are you sure?" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow">Destroy</a></td>

Comment: Your browser? Try in another browser also. Looks like problems with javascript. Show your layout (head) and application.js

Comment: Updated at first post. I gave tried with Mozilla, Chrome and CometBird.

Comment: Everything looks good. Do you have got any authentication in your app?

Comment: So I have no idea what's going on. Try to update your rails gem