# Rails Devise not Deleting Account

Tags: authentication, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am starting a new web app and I am using Devise for the authentication.

I have got Devise working with register, login, edit and viewing the user profile. The only problem I am having is clicking the 'Delete Account' just redirects to `/users` and doesn't actually delete the user. What am I doing wrong?

The delete account button

```
= link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :method => :delete
```

As far as I know, I haven't changed anything that would break this. The delete account button I want to use is

```
= negative_trash_button_link_to "Cancel my account", registration_path(resource_name), :method => :delete, :confirm => "You sure?"
```

The `negative_trash_button_link_to` is in the css3buttons gem.

Edit: My `routes.rb`

```
resources :posts

ActiveAdmin.routes(self)

devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config

root :to => "home#index"

devise_for :users do
  get "/users/sign_out" => "devise/sessions#destroy", :as => :destroy_user_session
end
resources :users, :only => :show
```

Comment: Are your routes are off? Try running `rake routes` to make sure that you have a delete route for `/users`.

Comment: Yep I do - http://i.qyk.in/tcmhS.png

Comment: Have now added my routes.rb file

Answer (score 1):

It would be helpful to tell us the rails version and the javascript libraries / frameworks that you have installed.

If you are using jquery or any other framework is working, test if it is working in general if is is using the appropriate helpers (for example the jquery-rails helpers in case of jquery). Most probably is a javascript issue, check also for any javascript errors.

Comment: The rails version is 3.1.1. And I am using jQuery, the one which is bundled with Rails in application.js

Answer (score 0):

Look your javascript console. You seems to have a javascript error which prevent the request to be sent.

Do you have the alert "Are you sure?" before the redirection ?

Comment: I am getting no alert's popping up.

Comment: After adding the code from here, I am getting the pop ups now - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3784633/delete-destroy-is-not-working-in-rails-3-with-jquery/5923346#5923346

But it now shows 'Template is missing'. "Missing template shots/destroy, inherited_resources/base/destroy, application/destroy"

Comment: Actually it works deleting the user with that code! :)

Now I would like to delete an image or 'shot' when I click the destroy button on the image. How would I do that as it is showing that error?